# alternate of blob type in hibernate-core.4.1.4.Final.jar

Tags: hibernate

In my project earlier i was using **hibernate-core.3.6.5.Final** jar which had "public static final BlobType BLOB = BlobType.INSTANCE;". Now i need to upgrade hibernate core jar to **hibernate-core.4.1.4.Final** jar. Which is not supporting BlobType.

Please do suggest how i can manage the BlobType support after upgrading to 4.1.4.Final jar.

Comment: i am using hibernate 4.1.8 final and there is org.hibernate.type.BlobType still available?

Comment: thanks Nils, i got it. Will use BlobType.INSTANCE instead of Hibernate.BLOB of hibernate-core.3.6.5.Final